# Are there portable ways of modifying environment variables?

Tags: c, environment-variables, c11

I notice that the C standard defines the getenv() function but that (7.22.4.2)

> the method for altering the environment list [is]
>   implementation-deﬁned.

I'm trying to have my program work on as many hosted C implementations as possible, is there a good general way to check if an implementation has a method to set an environment variable and what that method is, or will I have to take it on a case-by-case basis? Also, the wording of that quote suggests to me that there must be SOME method for each implementation, is that understanding correct?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How would such a system implement getenv()?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: done, but I'd let the question sit for a while because you may very well get better answers and people are more likely to add such an answer if there is no accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have an implementation of C on a system that does not have environment variables. So by that token you you cannot conclude that all host platforms support environment variables. However, that's pretty much nitpicking. You will have to deal with this on a case by case basis but you'll find `putenv()` pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Example of such; C compilers for most embedded systems that are running on a microkernel rather than on a Posix/Unix, or Dos/Windows style OS) very seldom have environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

[setenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv) is the chap you need.

Comment: Sure, on POSIX systems. I'm interested in more than just POSIX though.

Comment: Windows C implementations that I know of offer `setenv` and the rather more convenient `putenv`.